# Beautify pandas.DataFrame.apply calls if they applied to same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have such data preprocessing code:

```py
df['age'] = df['resume'].apply(lambda x: x['age'] if 'age' in x else None)
df['gender'] = df['resume'].apply(lambda x: x['gender']['id'] if 'gender' in x else None)
...
```

All `.apply` calls are applied to `df['resume']` column

Is there any more elegant record?

Comment: What is the data type of `resume` column?  could you add sample input?

Comment: Do ou mind to produce a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

You may define the lambda functions used to process your column in a separated dictionary indexed by the output column names, so that you can apply them all with a single for loop.

Sample code:

```
preprocess_functions = {
    "age": lambda x: x["age"] if "age" in x else None,
    "gender": lambda x: x["gender"]["id"] if "gender" in x else None
}

for out_col, fun in preprocess_functions.items():
    df[out_col] = df["resume"].apply(fun)
```

But this is just programming style, a more pandas-driven solution may be available depending on the data structure and on the processing required.